# Can some tell me how to make this script check for the password before it starts the upload process instead of after the file is uploaded?

Tags: upload, passwords

Can some tell me how to make this script check for the password before it starts the upload process instead of after the file is uploaded? Some of the files I need uploaded are big and it sucks to wait till the file is uploaded to before it tells me that the password was wrong.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>ES Simple Uploader</title>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
      <meta name="generator" content="handmade" />
        <style type="text/css">
        <!--
            body {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                font-size: 14px;
                background-color: #DDDDDD;
            }
            .cnt {
                text-align: center;
            }
            .cnt_welcome {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .cnt_powered {
                font-size: 14px;
                font-weight: bold;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .cnt_small {
                font-size: 12px;
                text-align: center;
                padding-top: 50px;
            }
            .head_line {
                background-color: #BBBBBB;
            }
            .main_table {
                border: solid 1px #9D9992;
                font-size: 13px;
            }
            h4 {
                font-size: 12px;
                color: #DD0000;
                text-align: center;
            }
            .button {
                border: 1px solid #55555;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
    -->
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?
    include("config.php");

    function path_options()
    {
     global $upload_dirs;
      $option = "";
      foreach ($upload_dirs as $path => $pinfo)
      {
        $option .= '<option value="'.$path.'">'.$pinfo["name"].'</option>';
      }
     return $option;
    }

    function check_vals()
    {
     global $upload_dirs, $err;
        if (!ini_get("file_uploads")) { $err .= "HTTP file uploading is blocked in php configuration file (php.ini). Please, contact to server administrator."; return 0; }
        $pos = strpos(ini_get("disable_functions"), "move_uploaded_file");
        if ($pos !== false) { $err .= "PHP function move_uploaded_file is blocked in php configuration file (php.ini). Please, contact to server administrator."; return 0; }
      if (!isset($_POST["path"]) || (strlen($_POST["path"]) == 0)) { $err .= "Please fill out path"; return 0; }
      if (!isset($upload_dirs[$_POST["path"]])) { $err .= "Incorrect path"; return 0; }
      if (!isset($_POST["pwd"]) || (strlen($_POST["pwd"]) == 0)) { $err .= "Please fill out password"; return 0; }
      elseif ($_POST["pwd"] != $upload_dirs[$_POST["path"]]["password"]) { $err .= "The upload password is incorrect"; return 0; }
      if (!isset($_FILES["userfile"])) { $err .= "Empty file"; return 0; }
      elseif (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])) { $err .= "Empty file"; return 0; }
     return 1;
    }

    $err = ""; $status = 0;
    if (isset($_POST["upload"])) {
      if (check_vals()) {
        if (filesize($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"]) > $max_file_size) $err .= "Maximum file size limit: $max_file_size bytes";
        else {
          if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"], $upload_dirs[$_POST["path"]]["dir"].$_FILES["userfile"]["name"])) {
                    $status = 1;
                }
          else $err .= "There are some errors!";
        }
      }
    }

    if (!$status) {
      if (strlen($err) > 0) echo "<h4>$err</h4>";
    }
    else {
      echo "<h4>&quot;".$_FILES["userfile"]["name"]."&quot; was successfully uploaded.</h4>";
    }
    ?>
    <p class="cnt_welcome">Welcome to ES Simple Uploader v 1.1.</p>
    <p class="cnt">&laquo; <a href="http://www.energyscripts.com/Products/product2.html">Back to Product page</a> &laquo;</p>
    <p class="cnt">(Select folder, set it's password, then select a file to upload and click "Upload" button).
        <br />Note: 
            Folder: &quot;Images folder&quot;, Password: &quot;images&quot;;
            Folder: &quot;Docs&quot;, Password: &quot;docs&quot;;
            Folder: &quot;Common files&quot;, Password: &quot;common&quot;;
            Maximum file size: <?=$max_file_size/1024?> Kb.</p><br />
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?=$max_file_size?>" />
    <table class="main_table" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="head_line">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Folder:</td>
        <td><select name="path"><?=path_options()?></select></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="pwd" style="width: 217px;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Choose file:</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="userfile" style="width: 222px;" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="upload" value="Upload" class="button" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </p>
    <p class="cnt_powered">Powered by <a href="http://www.energyscripts.com" target="_blank">EnergyScripts</a></p>
    <p class="cnt_small">Find more power solution: <a href="http://www.energyscripts.com/Products/product1.html" target="_blank">ES File Upload &amp; Download Manager</a></p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: No one can show me how to do this?

Comment: The problem is that the password is sent in the request along with the file.  PHP can't read the `$_POST` data until the entire request is sent.